# Checking every array member in an if statement to look for a specific array member

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to create a system where I have a string array where each member says the same thing ("Empty") but an if statement/foreach combo changes just *one* of those "Empty"s to a "Full" when a button is clicked. So first I start the `if` statement with something like

```
if (inv[0] == "Empty" || inv[1] == "Empty" || inv[2] == "Empty")
```

etc till it covers each member of the array making sure that there is at least one "Empty" (for it's supposed to only change an "Empty" to "Full" if there actually is an "Empty").

After that, I think I'm supposed to use a `foreach`, but I'm not sure how.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated. If you need me to send me my code, let me know.

Comment: If you want to change the element you probably want to use a regular for loop. It sounds like you just want to find the first element that's empty and change it to full, so just loop until you find empty, change the value, and then break out of the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [ask], what's [on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]. People are more likely to read and answer your question if it's clearly stated and _not_ formatted like a wall of text. If you need help with Stack Overflow's markdown, see [formatting help](/help/formatting). [Any help would be appreciated is not a valid question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/843953). What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

You can find if any of item is empty like this.

```
 bool isEmptyFound = false;
 foreach (var item in inv)
    if (item.Equals("Empty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        isEmptyFound = true;
        break;
    }
 //if isEmptyFound == true there is atleast one item that is "Empty"
```

You can not change item value by foreach you need to use simple for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inv.Length; i++)
    if (inv[i].Equals("Empty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        inv[i] = "Full";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I can find StringComparison though. (I'm using unity) and the error msg here says that it doesn't exist in its current context. And what is OrdinalIgnoreCase if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: You can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=net-5.0 but in summary it compare two strings case insensitively. for unity to find it you can write System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase or add using System; at top of  you script.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [Array.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0) to find the index of a `Empty` and then change it to `Full`, like so:

```
int indexOfEmpty = Array.IndexOf(inv, "Empty");

//check if inv has a value set to "Empty"
if (indexOfEmpty != -1)
{
    //change the "Empty" we found at indexOfEmpty to "Full"
    inv[indexOfEmpty] = "Full";
}
```

If you are looking to do it manually with a loop, then you can just use a for loop like so:

```
bool foundEmpty = false;

for (int i = 0; i < inv.Length; i++)
{
    if (inv[i] == "Empty")
    {
        inv[i] = "Full";
    
        foundEmpty = true;

        break;
    }
}
```